# Django: Cannot run django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

```
Django==1.7
flup==1.0.2
python==2.6
stevedore==0.15
virtualenv==1.11.6
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1
```

I try and run `django-admin.py` but I keep getting this bizzare syntax error, all on a fresh install of django..

```
File "/home/ibusdep1/.virtualenvs/ibus/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
  from django.core import management
File "/home/ibusdep1/.virtualenvs/ibus/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 68
  commands = {name: 'django.core' for name in find_commands(__path__[0])}
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Django is installed in `/.virtualenv/(projectname)/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django` and it is within my $PYTHONPATH.

What could be throwing this syntax error?

Answer (score 7):

Django 1.7 is not compatible with Python 2.6

Django 1.7 & 1.8 requires Python 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, or 3.4.
See [What Python version can I use with Django?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django)

The error you see there is a dict comprehension, added in Python 3 & 2.7+.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.7 only supports Python 2.7 +, not Python 2.6

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/